# How do I prevent HTML button from being double clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div id="spanCheckout" class="checkout-section clearfix">
  <a href="view_cart.asp" class="btn btn-link">
    <i class="icon-left"></i> Return to Cart</a>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" onclick="doCheckout(this.form,'checkoutButton');" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
      <i class="icon-basket"></i> [checkout3_submitbutton]
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Good evening, We recently began to see numerous duplicate charges on our e-commerce site from double button clicks at checkout. Could someone help with the code needed to disable and perhaps grey out the Checkout button after the first click to prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: maybe hide the button after click

Comment: Would love to, but how?

Comment: When the button is clicked, you can apply the `disabled` attribute to the button. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu9emv86/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<button onclick="handleCheckout()">Checkout</button>
```

Javascript:

```
let canCheckout = true;

function handleCheckout(){
  if(canCheckout){
    canCheckout = false;

    // Procced to checkout ...
  }
}
```

When someone clicks the button on the first time, he will change the boolean state to false, preventing the code from executing multiple times.